# Get centroid of a polygon shape in Bing Map in javascript

Tags: javascript, bing-maps

I want to get centroid of a polygon shape in Bing Map in javascript. Shape could be a triangle, rectangle, pentagon, square, hexagon etc. I am new to bing map. Pls help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Bing Maps V8 control has a spatial math library available as a module. One of the calculations is for getting the centroid of shapes. A code sample of how to get the centroid of a polygon can be found here: http://www.bing.com/api/maps/sdk/mapcontrol/isdk#getCentroid+JS

Documentation on the spatial math library can be found here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/mt712834.aspx

Additional code samples can be found here:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt750642.aspx

Comment: Wonder why someone would vote this down when it points to official documentation on how to accomplish what the user asked. And yes, posting links instead of copy/pasting code is ok when the link points to the official documentation. This has been discussed at length many times on stack overflow.